# Dynamically modify ElasticSearch query using Perl

Tags: perl, elasticsearch

At work I have a script made by people who aren't there any more. It is used to retrieve an XML file with a node looking like this:

```
 <query maxresults='15000'>
      <![CDATA[                                                                         
         and(                                                                            
                 isavailable:1,                                 
                 not(designation:string("test wine", mode="or")),                
                 visibility:10,                                                   
                 bestprice:>0                                                        
         )                                                                               
       ]]>
  </query>
```

We are using Perl for this. The goal is to modify the FAST request contained inside the node to dynamically add some parameters (e.g. limit the results with the "maxresults" attribute). This part of the code works, but we are switching to ElasticSearch and I need to change the code so it works.

Problem is, I can't find a reliable way to modify an ElasticSearch query with Perl. So far I did this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
use Search::Elasticsearch;

my $json = 
'{"query":
    {"bool":
        {"must":
            [
             {"term":
                {"isavailable":"1"}
             },
             {"term":
                {"visibility":"10"}
             },
             {"range":
                {"bestprice":
                    {"gt":"0"}
                }
             }

            ],
         "must_not":
            [{"regexp":
                {"designation":"[Tt]+[Ee]+[Ss]+[Tt]+"}
             },
             {"regexp":
                {"designation":"[Ww]+[Ii]+[Ne]+[Ee]+"}
             }
            ]
        }
    }
 }';

my $result = decode_json($json);
```

But it gives me a hash instead of an object and I'm getting a headache trying to dynamically modify this hash just to add (for example):

```
{"regexp": {"designation":"[Ff]+[Oo]+"}}
```

to the array inside the "must_not" object.

I tried to do this:

```
my %must = (must_not => [{"regexp" => 
                                        {"designation" => "[Ff]+[Oo]+"}
                           }
                          ]);


$result{"query"} = \%must;

print keys(%{$result{query}});
```

But this simply replaces the whole node content with the %must hash and I can't find a way to properly append it. I tried to push a hash inside the array contained in the must_not object but I only get errors.

I'm really puzzled by this situation, especially since I'm not really a Perl expert so any help is more than welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: If you convert something from JSON, you get a plain data structure. There are no objects in Perl by default. You need to modify the data structure, that's correct. You have to go in completely or it will be replaced, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an object because Perl does not by default work with objects. If you want an object, you need to have a class, and then instantiate it. But `decode_json` can't do that. All it does is return a complex data structure.

To add another entry to the array ref that holds the filters inside of that data structure, you need to [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) it in. For that you need to dereference the array ref, because `push` does not like to operate on references. Perl will do the right thing for you with the following syntax.

```
#    this dereferences the array ref for push
#    |                                       |
push @{ $result->{query}->{bool}->{must_not} }, {  # the { starts a new hash ref
    "regexp" => { 
        "designation" => "[Ff]+[Oo]+", # we like trailing commas in Perl
    },
};
```

If you have a very new Perl (5.24), you can also use the post-fix deref syntax here, which is a bit cleaner to read.

```
push $result->{query}->{bool}->{must_not}->@, { ... };
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm now able to do exactly what I want, and you provided a very neat explanation of what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You can work directly with the hash reference `decode_json` returns. For example,

1. get a reference to your `must_not` array

   ```
   my $mustNots = $result->{query}->{bool}->{must_not};
   ```
2. add a filter to this array by pushing a hash ref

   ```
   push(@{$mustNots}, {"regexp" => {"designation" => "[Ff]+[Oo]+"}});
   ```
3. you now have a third entry in `must_not`, `print encode_json($result);` gives

   ```
   {
       "query": {
           "bool": {
               "must": [
                   {
                       "term": {"isavailable": "1"}
                   },
                   {
                       "term": {"visibility": "10"}
                   },
                   {
                       "range": {"bestprice": {"gt": "0"}}
                   }
               ],
               "must_not": [
                   {
                       "regexp": {
                           "designation": "[Tt]+[Ee]+[Ss]+[Tt]+"
                       }
                   },
                   {
                       "regexp": {
                           "designation": "[Ww]+[Ii]+[Ne]+[Ee]+"
                       }
                   },
                   {
                       "regexp": {
                           "designation": "[Ff]+[Oo]+"
                       }
                   }
               ]
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help, combining your answer to @simbabque answer, I now understand what was my issue!